# Calculus rate questions!

Tags: calculus

**Question 1:** Sand forms a comical pile whose height is always $2$ times the base radius. If the base radius of the pile increases at a rate of $7~ \text{feet/hour}$, find the rate of change of the volume of the pile, when the base diamater is $10~ \text{feet}$.

**Question 2:** A box with a square base and open top must have a volume of $500~ \text{cubic inches}$. Find the dimensions of the box that minimize the amount of material used?

I got some weird answers so I was just wondering If I got it right. Got $200$ and $518$ respectively.

Comment: These are wrong.  If you show your work, we can probably find out where.

Comment: A **comical** pile? What's funny about a pile of sand? :P

Comment: Anyone know how to do these? Sorry, I am really bad at math.

Answer (score 1):

Q1:

Assuming that you meant a 'conical' pile the volume of this cone is $V = 1/3 \pi r^2h$
where $h = 2r$ so that $V = 2/3 \pi r^3$ and the rate of volume increase dependant on raduis is found from differentiation:
$$\frac{dV}{dr}=\pi r^2$$

It is known the radius of the cone increases at a rate of:
$$\frac{dr}{dt} =7$$

So the rate of voulme increase by time:
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dr} \times \frac{dr}{dt} = \pi r^2 \times 7 = 7\pi r^2$$
When the base diameter is 10 ft the radius is 5ft therefore:
$$\frac{dV}{dt} =7\pi (5)^2 \approx 550 f/h$$

Q2:

From the question:
$$V=lwh = l^2h = 500$$
$$\therefore h=500/l^2 $$
$$A=lw+4hw=l^2+4hl$$
$$\Rightarrow A=l^2+4l\times \frac{500}{l^2}$$
You want to minimise the area with respect to the open cuboids dimensions so:

$$\frac{dA}{dl}=2l + \frac{2000}{l^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow l=10$$
$$\Rightarrow h=5$$
So the dimensions are 10 x 10 x 5 inches with material area use of 300 square inches. Also  given that the dimensions are physical quantities $l > 0$
$$\therefore \frac{d^2A}{dl^2} > 0$$ so this answer is global minimum.